# why is there a compiler warning for boolean switch statement?

Tags: c++, c++17

why does the code below produce the warning:
"warning: switch condition has boolean value"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    const bool yes = true;
    
    switch (yes) {
        case true: cout << "sure" << endl; break;
        case false: cout << "nope" << endl;
    }
        
    return 0;

}
```

do switch statements only take numbers and chars?

Comment: Probably because it isn't needed.  You can just use `if (yes) cout << "sure" << endl; else cout << "nope" << endl;`

Comment: A warning doesn't (always) prevent code from compiling. It's a warning that you might be doing something you didn't mean to do. A lot of software engineering best practices (such as turning on compiler warnings) are to prevent us from making common mistakes. Like, it's legal to eat an anchovy sandwich, but if you try to do it, your spouse should ask if you mean to do what you're doing. You probably didn't mean to do it on purpose.

Comment: i'm using this as an example but am speaking about in general. in javascript switches take bool values and it is very useful. if you know if switches in c++ dont that would be useful. btw the code works fine but the compiler gives a warning.

Comment: @user13456653 *in javascript* -- Warning -- do not write C++ using another programming language as a model.  Trying to use other languages as models in writing C++ code will result in C++ code either buggy, less-efficient, or just weird-looking to a C++ programmer.  Your use of `bool` in a `switch` statement is an example.

Comment: What makes them useful in JavaScript over a simple if-else?  JavaScript is also not statically typed, so you have no guarantee of you're dealing with a boolean...

Comment: Try reading your compiler documentation - more likely to get opinion-based answers here.    The warning is not the same thing as a diagnosable error.   Most such warnings from compilers are based on stylistic concerns, for example (1) since a `bool` can only have two values, use of `switch` is considered inferior to a simple `if`/`else`   (2)   some style guides consider lack of a `default` clause in a switch is bad form, even if the `case`s cover all possible values of the type (3)   some compilers do warn on doing a `switch` on a `const` value.

Comment: @jamesdlin its because it makes much neater control functions for games

Comment: @user13456653 Again, how is it "neater" than if-else?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: @jamesdlin - S/he won't be able to.    S/he's stating opinion as fact to try an defend a subjectively chosen approach

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that the compiler-writers wanted to warn you about potential mistakes like this:

```
char c;
[...]

switch(c==getchar())  // oops!  Probably not what was intended
{
   case 'a':  cout << "you entered a" << endl; break;  // will never be called
   case 'b':  cout << "you entered b" << endl; break;  // will never be called

   // will always be called, because (c==getchar()) always evaluates to either 0 or 1
   default:   cout << "you entered something else: " << c << endl; break;  
}
```

... when you meant to write:

```
char c;
[...]

// works as advertised
switch(c=getchar())
{
   case 'a':  cout << "you entered a" << endl; break;
   case 'b':  cout << "you entered b" << endl; break;
   default:   cout << "you entered something else: " << c << endl; break;
}
```

Typically you wouldn't use `switch` on a boolean, since with just two possible cases, `if` or the ternary-operator would do just as well, e.g.:

```
if (yes) cout << "sure" << endl;
    else cout << "nope" << endl;
```

... or even

```
cout << (yes ? "sure" : "nope") << endl;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. the reason i'm asking is because normally in javascript game dev i use bools in switches a lot. thanks you again for the answer!

Comment: btw, could you explain what the examples mean? i am new to c++

Comment: The first example calls `getchar()`, compares its return-value to `c`, and jumps to the 'true' case if the two values are equal or to the 'false' case if they are not equal.  The second example calls `getchar()`, assigns that return-value to `c`, and jumps to the case that is equal to the value returned by `getchar()` and assigned to c.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quality of implementation issue. You are definitely allowed to have `bool` values in `switch` conditions.

Compilers try to warn about potential mistakes. `clang` is giving a wrong warning here, there's nothing dangerous about your code. You have exactly 2 case statements that evaluate to `true` and `false`.

Code like this:

```
switch(yes) {
  case 5: ...
  case 6: ...
}
```

should be diagnosed, and `gcc`, for example, does warn about such code, but doesn't issue a warning for your code. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cDhDpd).